# How can I skip the desktop while cycling through finder windows with cmd+`?

Tags: macos, finder

I often have to copy-paste files from 2 finder folders. I use the <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd> shortcut. But it cycles through Window 1 > Desktop > Window 2.

Is there a way to skip desktop?

Answer (score 2):

Desktop is a folder, so cycling between active folder is an expected behavior in Finder. The only way to achieve what you want is to hide Desktop by entering the command below.

```
defaults write com.apple.finder CreateDesktop FALSE
```

After this, cycling between window will happen to the folder you’ve opened. This suggestion is recommended only if you don’t use Desktop to place temporary files.

Comment: I use my desktop for temporary files, so I guess I won't be able to use it.

Comment: How about trying Unclutter for Mac to place temporary files. This way you can maintain a clean desktop, while cycling between window smoothly. :)

Comment: Completely forgot about CreateDesktop — oops :)

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to go back and forth between two windows several times in a row, you can alternate between <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>`</kbd> and <kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>`</kbd>, which goes the other way round.

Comment: Yes, it does work but hitting cmd+' twice is quicker than using shift. <Being Lazy>